# How to run process only once even if condition remains true

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, timer, conditional-statements

I have a function which grabs an image and processes it. The function works when a process signal is received from a PLC.
I have a timer which keeps checking for signal from PLC.
Once I receive the signal from PLC, the image is grabbed and processed, but the signal remains true till the processing is finished and the result is sent to robot, after which the robot sends a stop signal.
Sometimes, the processing happens quickly and before the robot could send the stop signal, the function runs again.

Here is the timer code:

```
     private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chksignal_robot(); //keep checking signal           

        if (textBox8.Text.Contains("process")) //
        {
            totalsheetcount++;

            grab_image();
            Thread.Sleep(200);               
            processimage();    
        }
    }
```

How do I make the method run just once although the signal still shows "process"(condition remains true)? and wait till the signal goes stop(condition goes false) and next process signal is received(condition becomes true again?

Comment: Can't you just use a boolean field, like `_isRunning`?  Or if this is multi-threaded, use a semaphore?

Comment: On a side note, `Thread.Sleep(200);` why are you sleeping the UI thread?

Comment: First idea would be: If chkSignal returns, disable timer. then do the magic, then check signal to go down, before restarting the timer. It's not really clear if you have some requirements regarding timing, though. So this is just a rough idea and may need serious adaption.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ After grabbing image, I wanted to wait for a few ms before the processing starts.

Comment: i dont understand your code. Is chksignal a blocking call? is chksignal setting textBox8.Text to "process" which starts the processing? it sounds like you need to check for a rising edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understood your code. But you could try this. It is a classical check for a rising edge (false -> true).

```
bool _oldSignal;

private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chksignal_robot(); //keep checking signal    

    var newSignal = textBox8.Text.Contains("process");
    var isRisingEdge = newSignal && (_oldSignal == false);
    _oldSignal = newSignal;

    if (isRisingEdge) //
    {
        totalsheetcount++;

        grab_image();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        processimage();
    }
}
```

Additional Note:

Thread.Sleep(200) will freeze your program. A more elegant solution is using Task.Delay() in combination with async/await keywords. This wont block your UI-Thread.

```
private async void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do some stuff
   await Task.Delay(200);  // wait 200 ms without freezing the UI.
   // do stuff after the 200 ms delay
}
```

Comment: Hi, bool newSignal = chksignal_robot(); doesnt work, it says that it cannot covert void to bool. chksignal_robot() keeps communicating witj PLC for textbox 8 to receive keyword "process". Used async task, thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: @Roshan so chksignal_robot sets textBox8 = "process" when the signal comes? And when the stop signal comes, it sets textBox8 to something else? to what? textBox8 = "stop"? how do you see in your application that the stop signal came?

Comment: Hi, stop signal sets textbox8 = "0".

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for all the time and help.

Comment: @Roshan good to hear. Next time try to add important details like chksignal changes the textbox to this and that in the question. That makes it for people easier to understand the problem and the code. It will increase the chance of getting an answer dramatically, and you will get it much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Could you setup a flag like below?

```
bool flag1=true;
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chksignal_robot(); //keep checking signal           

    if (textBox8.Text.Contains("process")   && flag1==true) //
    {
        flag1=false
        totalsheetcount++;

        grab_image();
        Thread.Sleep(200);               
        processimage();  
        flag1=true  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in a loop you have to take all signals etc..
and you can use bool value. Just this.

```cs
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

var maxsheet=30; //write correct!
bool processed=false;

while(totalsheetcount<maxsheet)
{
        chksignal_robot(); //keep checking signal           

        if (textBox8.Text.Contains("process")) //
        {
            totalsheetcount++;

            grab_image();
            Thread.Sleep(200);               
            if(!processed)
             processimage(); 
            processed=true;   
        }
}
    }
```